# How to move to next screen when button of viewclass in recycleview gets pressed that is on screen in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am working on the app that contains several stages on different screens so I chose RecycleView for stage screen. Now I just want to reach different screens by clicking different buttons of RecycleView having viewclass Button.

The code that I am providing is not the actual code but it is the part of that that is having the required screens. Just help me to access screen(name: 'first') by clicking button having text '1' of RV ,rest I will do myself.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView

Builder.load_string('''
<ExampleRV>:
    viewclass: 'Button'

    RecycleBoxLayout:

        size_hint_y: None
        size_hint_x: None
        pos_hint: {'x': 0,'top': 0}

        height: self.minimum_height
        width: self.minimum_width

        orientation: 'horizontal'

<Manager>:

    Screen:
        name: 'main'
        Button:
            text: "Press me"
            size_hint: 0.8, 0.2
            pos_hint: {"x":0.1, "y":0.1}
            on_release: root.current = 'next'
    Screen:
        name: 'next'
        ExampleRV:

    Screen:
        name: 'first'
        Button:
            text:'Press to go back'
            on_release:
                root.current= 'main'

''')

class ExampleRV(RecycleView):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ExampleRV, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.data = [{'text': str(x)} for x in range(1,21)]

class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass

sm = Manager()

class myApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom Buttons must be created that have the ScreenManager as their property and the names of the screens that are pressed when the button is changed and the Screen changed. That information must be sent through the data property. Considering the above I have modified your code generating 2 screen: first and second associated with 2 buttons:

```py
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivy.properties import ListProperty

from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


Builder.load_string(
    """
<ManagerButton@Button>:
    manager: None
    name_screen: ""
    on_press:
        self.manager.current = self.name_screen

<ExampleRV>:
    viewclass: 'ManagerButton'

    RecycleBoxLayout:

        size_hint_y: None
        size_hint_x: None
        pos_hint: {'x': 0,'top': 0}

        height: self.minimum_height
        width: self.minimum_width

        orientation: 'horizontal'

<Manager>:
    Screen:
        name: 'main'
        Button:
            text: "Press me"
            size_hint: 0.8, 0.2
            pos_hint: {"x":0.1, "y":0.1}
            on_release: root.current = 'next'
    Screen:
        name: 'next'
        ExampleRV:
            data: [ {"text": str(i), "manager": root, "name_screen": name} for i, name in enumerate(self.screen_names, 1) ]

    Screen:
        name: 'first'
        Button:
            text:'First: Press to go back'
            on_release:
                root.current= 'main'

    Screen:
        name: 'second'
        Button:
            text:'Second: Press to go back'
            on_release:
                root.current= 'main'

"""
)


class ExampleRV(RecycleView):
    screen_names = ListProperty(["first", "second"])


class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass


sm = Manager()


class myApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm


if __name__ == "__main__":
    myApp().run()
```

Comment: Amazing! You just solved my problem :) ,just one thing, can you tell little bit more about what have you done like what is done in data property, Thank you !!

Comment: And just one thing more, can you help me to change the position of these buttons of recycleview like in the middle of the screen instead of on top, Thank you very much!

Comment: @Tanishqchandra 1) You find it in the Kivy documentation but in summary data is a list of dictionaries that allows you to send information to the "viewclass", for example in your code you put a `data = [{"text": "foo"}]` and then when RecycleView create the views using the viewclass will use the data information, that is, the item will be passed as property to text something like: `for d in datas: create_view_from(viewclass) (text = "foo")`,

Comment: @Tanishqchandra  2) That task does not have nothing to do with your question so I will not do it, I think it is a good exercise for you to understand how the geometry of RecycleView works

Comment: Ok, thank you very much @eyllanesc for you help and cooperation !